# Symfony 2.3 FOSUserBundle.en.yml not registering override

Tags: symfony, translation, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override the default FOSUserBundle.en.yml from the FOS user-bundle.

I have the user bundle working fine, i have registered a user and logged in.

However when I copy the  FOSUserBundle.en.yml into my own UserBundle to override the wording Symfony doesn't seem to pick it up.

This is the path I have copied the transation file to:

> src/Blogger/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.ym

But no joy.. I have cleared the caches tried another browser but the change in the override will not come through.

I can place the change the in the original and see the changes:

> vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

To override the bundle, you should add this :

```
// src/Blogger/UserBundle/BloggerUserBundle.php
namespace Blogger\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class BloggerUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Here's a link from the docs : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html
All the steps you should follow are in there.

Comment: I have this already, i have overridden the login template. But the translation yml file is not being read for some reason..

Comment: Look at your path ``src/Blogger/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.ym`` You need an "l" at the end of your path. It's not ``FOSUserBundle.en.ym``; it should be ``.yml``
Are you sure the filename is correct ?

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo in stackoverflow. It has the l in my application